# Core Data of type NSInMemoryStoreType ignores entity's constraints

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data

I created mocked version of CoreData stack

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@testable import Companion

final class MockedDatabaseStackController: DatabaseStackControllerProtocol {

    let batchRequestsAvailable: Bool = false

    private lazy var managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle(for: type(of: self))])!

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
        description.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(
            name: "database",
            managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel
        )
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            // Check if the data store is in memory
            precondition( description.type == NSInMemoryStoreType )

            // Check if creating container wrong
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Create an in-mem coordinator failed \(error)")
            }
        }

        return container
    }()

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(didManagedObjectContextSave(notification:)),
                name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                object: nil
            )
    }

    @objc
    private func didManagedObjectContextSave(notification: Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.persistentContainer.viewContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification)
        }
    }
}
```

and I am using it to save some object:

```
private func executeAndSave<T>(_ executionBlock: @escaping ((NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> T)) -> Single<T> {
    let persistentContainer = stackController.persistentContainer

    return Single.create { observer in
        persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
            do {
                context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

                jsons.forEach {
                    let mo = type.init(context: context)
                    mo.update(withGatewayResponse: $0)
                }
                try context.save()

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    observer(.success(result))
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    observer(.error(error))
                }
            }
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

func save(jsons: [JSON], as type: GatewayObjectDeserializableAndSavable.Type) -> Single<Void> {
    if jsons.isEmpty {
        log.info("(\(type)) Nothing to save.")
        return .just(())
    }

    log.info("DatabaseHelper will save \(type)")

    return executeAndSave { context in
        jsons.forEach {
            let mo = type.init(context: context)
            mo.update(withGatewayResponse: $0)
        }
    }
}

// Example of usage:
databaseHelper.save(jsons: jsons, as: Herd.self)
```

I created constraints in database model, for example:
[image]

But it doesn't work. Objects duplicate in database.
[image]

Note that everything works fine in main target where I use this CoreData's stack:

```
final class DatabaseStackController: DatabaseStackControllerProtocol {

    // singleton
    static let controller = DatabaseStackController()

    private static let kDatabaseName = "database"
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = DatabaseStackController.buildDatabaseStack(onComplete: nil)

    let batchRequestsAvailable: Bool = true

    private init() {
        addNSMangedObjectContextObservers()
    }

    private static func buildDatabaseStack(onComplete: (() -> Void)?) -> NSPersistentContainer {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: kDatabaseName)
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            onComplete?()
        }

        return container
    }
}
```

Why it doesn't work? Is `NSInMemoryStoreType` not support CoreData's constraints? Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in Core Data :(

I have a little demo project for Core Data's *Unique Constraint*.  I confirmed that it works as expected [except for some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108300/core-data-unique-constraint-raises-exceptions-when-it-works), always merging all duplicates, with the SQLite store.  I then pasted in your `MockedDatabaseStackController` class and used its `persistentContainer.viewContext` with `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` set.  Result: It seems to merge the first set of duplicates on the first *save* operation but none after that.  I then switched back to my Core Data stack, except I changed the store type to `NSInMemoryStoreType`.  Result: It also fails to work, the same as your `MockedDatabaseStackController`.

The SQLite database which underlies Core Data's SQLite store supports the *UNIQUE* constraint in [its SQL](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).  I hope someone can prove me wrong, but, sadly, I suspect that Apple used this feature of SQLite to implement the *Unique Constraint* feature in Core Data, but failed to add to [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html) the fact that it only works for the SQLite store.

I've submitted this to Apple Bug Reporter: 50725935.

As to your test, I think that you should modify it to create a temporary SQLite store.  There are in fact some features which are on the other side of the Venn diagram – supported by the in-memory store but *not* supported by the SQLite store.  Testing with an in-memory store could leave holes in your test coverage.

Comment: Still the case on iOS 13 unfortunately.

Comment: Jerry: I suspect the same about the quick Apple implementation, as of Dec 2020 this bug still exists. The quick fix is as you suggest, using a temporary SQLite for tests. I was using `storeType: NSInMemoryStoreType` for tests for faster execution...